# Multiple JSON schemas (products) - how to load correct schema based on keywords?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, jsonschema

**Question**

Where should search keywords and brand names go in a JSON schema (multiple files) in order to search multiple JSON schemas (100-1000s) and select the applicable one?

**Background**

Not new to programming, I'm relatively new to JSON.

I'm in process of creating a JSON Schema Builder and Form Generator from the schema in Angular - [Work In Progress Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhvhcm).

I plan to generate a form (from 1 x schema) for approx 100s (potentially 1000s) of products.

Against each product are search keywords and brand names and I plan to use these to search for a product schema (loads the schema hence the form).

**Possible ideas**:

1. Keep one huge single JSON file (I want to avoid this)
2. Keep a meta json schema with keywords in an annotation, load this and use this to select and load correct schema

*search-schema.json*

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "plywood.json": {
          "description": "plywood ply" <---- keywords
      },
      "pens.json": { ...
  }
}
```

3. Save schemas to a database and use database functionality to search for correct schema (is this avoidable/desirable/prefered?).

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you are actually asking. Could you expand your question with some examples? From the limited information, it doesn't sound like there's any "standard" or "best" way to do what you want. It's likely to be "whatever works for you".

Comment: I don't want to expand the question given it's at risk of being too broad. Simply put, is there a JSON way of adding search terms to a set of schemas and where should these be (on each schema / on some meta schema) for the purposes of selection of a specfic schema using such a keyword say "pen"? It's a design question - is JSON suseptable to this aim (some variant of idea 2) or is this a non-starter and therefore should I look outside JSON (i.e. idea 3)

Comment: I already think this question is too broad. By expand, I mean provide more detail. JSON is whatever you want it to be. JSON is an encoding (or serialisation) of objects, arrays, and values. I don't know what you are expecting. Is there some parallel in another serialisation format you've used that leads you to ask this question?

Comment: Do you really need a schema? With non-sql db, you can just store what you want. They don't need to be the same.

Comment: @Antediluvian yes, needs to be schema. Forms are created from the schema. No experience with no-sql though I imagine if I save each schema as a document I’d still need to save keywords somewhere